# update form from other page primefaces

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

i would like to update form from other page when the user click on button it will show a form in other page and update his fields like this:

```
<p:commandButton value="Edit" actionListener="#{cubeMan.setUpdateCubeFilds()}" update=":form2"/>
```

and this is my form in the other page:

```
 <h:form id="form2">


        <p:panelGrid columns="2"> 

        <p:outputLabel value="Name :" for="name_cube"/>
                <p:inputText id ="name_cube" value="#{cubeMan.cubUpdate.name_cube}" required="true"/>

        <p:outputLabel value="Description :" for="description_cube"/>
                <p:inputText id ="description_cube" value="#{cubeMan.cubUpdate.description_cube}" required="true"/>
                <p:outputLabel value="Caption:" for="caption_cube"/>
                <p:inputText id ="caption_cube" value="#{cubeMan.cubUpdate.caption_cube}" required="true"/>
                <p:outputLabel value="Visible:" />
                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{cubeMan.cubUpdate.visible}" ></p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                <p:outputLabel value="Enabled:" />
                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{cubeMan.cubUpdate.enabled}" ></p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                <p:outputLabel value="Cache:" />
                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{cubeMan.cubUpdate.cache}" ></p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
        </p:panelGrid>
    <p:commandButton value="Edit" actionListener="#{cubeMan.updateThisCube()}" update=":form2"></p:commandButton>
     <p:commandButton value="Add" action="#{cubeMan.makeCube()}" ></p:commandButton>
     <p:commandButton value="Delete" action="#{cubeMan.deleteCube()}"/>
      <p:commandButton id="EditCube" value="+" type="button" onclick="PF('dlg3').show();" />

     </h:form>
```

and my form it's not in the some page so what should i do plz ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the include in your main page and put your src page there and it will be works:

```
 <ui:include src="/SelectedCube.xhtml" />
```